# Tekton sidecar: docker daemon failing to start

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have a Tekton pipeline that builds and pushes a Docker image to a private repository. The task that handles this uses a DinD sidecar. Originally, it worked just fine, but it's started failing with the error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`. This was an intermittent error at first, but now it seems to be happening every time I try to run the pipeline. I tried making it wait until it can connect to the daemon, in case it was a timing issue, but it ends up just waiting forever. What might be preventing the Docker daemon from starting, or preventing the task from connecting to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older Docker-DIND images used to create that socket file, a while ago. Nowadays, you would have to use a TCP socket.

See TektonCD samples to patch your Tasks: https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/blob/main/task/docker-build/0.1/docker-build.yaml